# Magento Error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:

Tags: database, magento

Recently, we migrated a selection of our products, customers, orders etc from Zen Cart to Magento.
The first migration went flawlessly and indexing was fine, so we went on and migrated all of our products etc.   After migrating all the products, we tried to run the various re-indexing and we get an error.    Below is the error log.

```
Error:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ecigexpr_newecx`.`cataloginventory_stock_status`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATINV_STOCK_STS_WS_ID_CORE_WS_WS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON)

2013-01-23T23:43:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ecigexpr_newecx`.`cataloginventory_stock_status`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATINV_STOCK_STS_WS_ID_CORE_WS_WS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON)
Trace: #0 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(48): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'cataloginventor...', Array, false)
#7 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Indexer_Stock), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'cataloginventor...', Array, false)
#8 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('cataloginventor...', 'cataloginventor...', false)
#9 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Indexer/Stock.php(251): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#10 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Indexer_Stock->reindexAll()
#11 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#12 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(249): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#16 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#17 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /home/ecigexpr/public_html/ecximproved/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
```

I can see clearly that the problem is in cataloginventory_stock_status and website_id, but am at a loss on how to correct it.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We never could find a real solution to this, but we ended up moving to another server and installing a fresh copy of magento.  We then imported the db in phpmyadmin and all was ok.  As nothing in the db had changed, it leads me to believe that perhaps a lock file, corruption or something else was causing the issue on the file side (as opposed to within the db).  If you are experiencing this, you may want to start with clearing out cache and lock files and overwriting with your backup.   If that does not work, export the db, reinstall magento and import the db is the only solution I could come up with.   While not the optimal solution, we no longer are having the issue.